# I want to "Gatsby Build" and deploy to a subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I read https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/ and I added the following to gatsby-configs.js.

```
{
  pathPrefix: "/modules/custom/gatsby/gatsby-shopify-starter/public",
},
```

And, I execute `sudo gatsby build --prefix-paths` on terminal.
But, I got this error message.

```
ERROR

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type s  tring. Received an instance of Object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gatsby's `pathPrefix` only prepends a string to your projects routes (url). Your deployment script(s) should handle where the public folder ends up on your server. If you really want to publish your gatsby project to somewhere other than `/public` (locally) You will propbably need to do something like use `fs` and `path` in `onPostBuild` in gatsby-node.js to move everything over to another directory. At the time or writing this, Gatsby doesn't directly support alternative build directories so you are on your own when using gatsby develop or gatsby serve to view this locally.

Try something like this in gatsby-node.js but change the paths to serve your needs. This example will publish your project to `/public/blog` rather than the default `/public` and is just a proof of concept but I tested it and it works:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.onPostBuild = function() {
  fs.renameSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), path.join(__dirname, 'public-blog'));

  fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

  fs.renameSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public-blog'), path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'blog'));
};
```